# Recursive Tree Math Invariant

Tags: combinatorics

"The Mathematical Forest is grown in a two-dimensional plane, where trees can only grow on points with integer coordinates. To start with, there are no trees at all. The foresters plant the first tree at (0,0). Each year, they carry out tree planting according to the following rule. If there is a tree on the point (m,n) but there are no trees on the points (m+1,n) and (m,n+1), then they can choose to remove the tree on (m, n) and plant new trees on the points (m,n+1) and (m+1,n). For an integer k≥1, the k-th diagonal consists of all points (m,n) with m+n=k−1. Is it possible for the foresters to arrange their planting so that eventually there are no trees on the first 2 diagonals? What about the first 3 diagonals? 4 diagonals? Can you generalize?"

I found that it is not possible to do >= 3 diagonals. However, I was not able to prove it. Does anyone have a rigorous proof for it?

Comment: This problem comes from PROMYS, whose application is now over.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the current status of the contest this question is from. I've deleted my comment above about the connection to the [The Mathematical Forest is grown in a two-dimensional plane, where trees can only grow on points with integer coordinates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564025/602049) post and it being locked due to an ongoing contest. Welcome to Math SE and I hope somebody will help you with figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a famous (very) old math olympiad problem. I'm surprised that they are still using it ...

A proof that you can never evacuate from the first 3 diagonals:

Assign to every integral point a "weight". The point $(m, n)$ is assigned weight $2^{-(m + n)}$. Thus the origin $(0, 0)$ is assigned weight $1$.

This weight assignment has the following property: whenever you remove one tree from $(m, n)$ and plant two trees on $(m + 1, n)$ and $(m, n + 1)$, the total weight of the trees does not change.

Since you originally have just one tree at $(0, 0)$, the total weight will remain $1$ at any time, however you replant the trees.

Now comes one important observation: at any given time, there can be at most (and in fact exactly) one tree on the semi-line $\{(m, 0): m \geq 0\}$.

And symmetrically, the same is true for the semi-line $\{(0, n): n \geq 0\}$.

---

To conclude the argument, let us assume that after finitely many steps we arrive at a status where there is no tree up to the third diagonal.

We then sum up all the weights in the possible points where trees can grow. These are then $\{(m, n): m, n \geq 1, m + n \geq 3\}$, together with the two semi-lines $\{(m, 0): m \geq 3\}$ and $\{(0, n): n \geq 3\}$.

The sum of the weights in the "main chunk", i.e. $\{(m, n): m, n \geq 1, m + n \geq 3\}$, is equal to $\frac 3 4$. This is a simple exercise in summing up geometric sequences.

On each of the semi-lines, since there can be at most one tree, the weight is at most $\frac 1 8$.

These all add up to $\frac 3 4 + \frac 1 8 + \frac 1 8 = 1$, which is exactly the total weight of all trees.

This means that, if this situation is ever possible, then every point on the main chunk must have a tree planted. This obviously cannot be achieved in finitely many steps, leading to a contradiction.